# Could not load nib in bundle on iPhone device" SIGBART"

Tags: iphone, xcode, nib

I am using this code to load my view but the error is occured, Here is the code:

```
charecterprofile *View = [[charecterprofile alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:View animated:YES];
    [View release];
```

But it does not work. What will i do?

Comment: You have one strange way of defining names on your identifiers, thats for sure!

Comment: whats the error on the consol

Comment: Are you creating your view controller from a NIB (XIB)?

Comment: i am adding UIViewcontrolling having .h , .m and xib file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
charecterprofile *view = [[charecterprofile alloc] initWithNibName:@"NIB" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

instead of just allocating the view controller object. Her NIB is your xib file name without the .xib extension.